# Using Google Email Markup with PHPMailer and Google SMTP server not working

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, google-schemas

I'm trying to use `Email Markups` from [schema.org](http://schema.org) and Google to confirm a newsletter subscription ( using [One-click-actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action) ) to view a "Confirm subscription" button in my Gmail inbox.
 The email will be sent using `PHPMailer` class and Google SMTP servers. So, this is my `PHPMailer` configuration to use correct Google's servers:

```
$phpMailer=new PHPMailer;
$phpMailer->isSMTP();
$phpMailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
$phpMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpMailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpMailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$phpMailer->Port = 465;
$phpMailer->Username = "myGoogleEmail";
$phpMailer->Password = "myGooglePassword";
$phpMailer->isHTML(true);
```

And this is my mail's HTML body, copied-pasted from Google's docs:

```
<html>
        <body>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "EmailMessage",
          "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "ConfirmAction",
            "name": "Conferma Iscrizione",
            "handler": {
              "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
              "url": "$url"
            }
          },
          "description": "Conferma iscrizione newsletter"
        }
        </script>
        <p>Grazie per il tuo interesse!</p>
        <p>Fai click sul link sottostante per confermare la tua iscrizione alla newsletter di Dotmedia<br>
        <a href="'.$url.'">FAI CLICK QUI PER CONFERMARE</a>
        </p>
        <p>
        La presente conferma è indispensabile per verificare che la registrazione sia stata effettivamente richiesta dal titolare dell’indirizzo email sopra indicato.<br>
        L\'iscrizione non sarà confermata senza avere fatto click sul link riportato sopra.
        </p>
        <p>Grazie</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Obviously I've just changed `potentialAction.name` and `potentialAction.url` and I've double-checked that they're right.

While sending mail, I assure that everything works fine by viewing `PHPMailer` debug logs, and mail is sent to my inbox, but "Confirm subscription" button isn't showing up.
As written in [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema) if mail sender and recipient are the same, Google won't check for registration requirements.
So I've set `PHPMailer->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com')` but it's still not working at all.

Testing on Google's app script ( you can find Email Markup test [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial) ) and pasting my mail's HTML ( the one here ) it works, and I can actually see the button in my Gmail inbox.

I've been stuck since this morning, but I still can't find a solution to this, I guess it could be a `PHPMailer` SMTP server misconfiguration, but I can't find anything wrong.

Side note: I've already disabled Google's block for unsafe applications.

Comment: If you view source on the received message, does it contain the expected markup? Have you tried using the microdata markup? Take a look at the xoauth support in PHPMailer if you want to be able to work without having to enable less secure apps.

Comment: Yes, it does contain the expected markup, even if it's JSON-LD or simple markup

Comment: I recall looking at this when it first came out and found there was some condition you had to fulfil before gmail would do anything with these widgets - possibly something like DKIM signing, though I don't remember exactly what. In short, gmail doesn't always enable these.

Comment: Yes, I saw that Google requires some security parameters in order to enable those widgets. But, as written in the docs, they're not required if you send those emails to yourself.

Comment: You are right, if you send it to yourself it should work, but only if you use Apps Script to send the email  https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/apps-script-tutorial.  If you use a different method to send the email it won't work. For it to work with your own SMTP service, you first have to register with Google: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google